# Is It Possible to Alias data.frame names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

When working with some data standards, it would be simpler to have multiple ways to look at the columns of a data.frame.  As one specific example, when working with SDTM data for clinical trials, each data type (like labs or vital signs) has a column for time point named "LBTPT" for labs and "VSTPT" for vital signs.  When loading the data, ideally, I'd like to be able to refer to that column as either "LBTPT" or "TPT".

Specifically, I'd like to find a way to make something like the following work:

```
d <- data.frame(LBTPT=1:3)
d <- alias_column(d, TPT="LBTPT")
d$TPT == d$LBTPT
```

But, I'd like for the data to only be stored once-- it is just an alias not a copy.

And, for bonus points, it would work in a "do what I mean" way when interacting with functions like `merge`, `names<-`, `bind_rows`, etc.

Comment: Your example doesn’t really convey to me how this would be useful, understanding that each column has to have a unique name anyway. How would this be iseful?

Comment: What do you need to do with the data? This is essentially the paradigm of the tidyverse packages, where you refer back to bare column names while operating on a data frame

Comment: There is no need to create an alias. Just rename the column either using base R: names(r) <- ... or using dplyr or data.table packages - whichever you prefer.

Comment: I know I can rename data.frame columns using `names(x) <- ...` or `dplyr::rename` or other methods.  There are several reasons for wanting to be able to use the alias: 1) packages that I do not control are looking for the standard name (e.g. "LBTPT") while new code that I am writing would be easier to generalize with the alias (e.g. "TPT") and 2) in a different example mapping data to the original data source would be easier with both the name for standards compliance (which I don't control) and the name from the original data (which I don't control) linked.

Comment: I believe this is not possible. R has copy-on-modify semantics, and even though you could bind a variable to two different names (and it would be saved only once initially, i.e. each name would point to the same memory), as soon as you modify one, R will make a copy. I can't think of any way to avoid this, certainly not with pure R.

Comment: @Alexis  data.table can do it.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My sense is you can do this, through the use of [R6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html) and active bindings.

- R6 methods belong to objects, not generics.
- R6 objects are mutable: the usual copy-on-modify semantics do not apply.

With this in mind, we can create an example. Here we create two views of the iris dataset where we access the same column using two different column names. Changes via either column name will update the shared private iris data set.

I am a fan of R6 as it offers a way to maintain (in this case) dataframe reference semantics while allowing multiple ways to reference the dataset.

nb. I hope this points you in the right direction.

## R6 Example (Here we create two views of the iris dataset):

```
require(R6)
data(iris)

dataframe_factory <- R6Class(
  "dataframe_factory",
  portable = FALSE,
  lock_objects = FALSE,
  private = list(
    ..iris_data = iris
  ),
  active = list(
    # add the binding here
    Sepal.Length = function(x, ...) {
      if ( missing(x) ) {
        private$..iris_data$Sepal.Length
      } else {
        private$..iris_data$Sepal.Length[...] <<- x
      }
    },

    another.Sepal.Length = function(x, ...) {
      if ( missing(x) ) {
        private$..iris_data$Sepal.Length
      } else {
        private$..iris_data$Sepal.Length[...] <<- x
      }
    }
    )
)

# Create the DataFrame
my_Dataframe <- dataframe_factory$new()

# Retrieve the alias
my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length
my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length

my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1] <- 5
my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1]

my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[2] <- 8
my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[2]

my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length
my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length

head(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length,2)
my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1:2]

identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length, my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length)
identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1], my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[1])
identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1:2], my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[1:2])
```

## R6 Console Console Output:

```
> require(R6)

> data(iris)

> dataframe_factory <- R6Class(
+   "dataframe_factory",
+   portable = FALSE,
+   lock_objects = FALSE,
+   private = list(
+     ..iris_data = iris
 .... [TRUNCATED] 

> # Create the DataFrame
> my_Dataframe <- dataframe_factory$new()

> # Retrieve the alias
> my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length
  [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7 5.1
 [21] 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1
 [41] 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2
 [61] 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7
 [81] 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7
[101] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0
[121] 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9
[141] 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9

> my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length
  [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7 5.1
 [21] 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1
 [41] 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2
 [61] 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7
 [81] 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7
[101] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0
[121] 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9
[141] 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9

> my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1] <- 5

> my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1]
[1] 5

> my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[2] <- 8

> my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[2]
[1] 8

> my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length
  [1] 5.0 8.0 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7 5.1
 [21] 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1
 [41] 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2
 [61] 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7
 [81] 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7
[101] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0
[121] 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9
[141] 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9

> my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length
  [1] 5.0 8.0 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7 5.1
 [21] 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1
 [41] 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2
 [61] 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7
 [81] 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7
[101] 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0
[121] 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9
[141] 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9

> head(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length,2)
[1] 5 8

> my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1:2]
[1] 5 8

> identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length, my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length)
[1] TRUE

> identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1], my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[1])
[1] TRUE

> identical(my_Dataframe$Sepal.Length[1:2], my_Dataframe$another.Sepal.Length[1:2])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This was the basis for the way that I started my code below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to contradict my own comment and give you an example that could potentially work,
but is what some people (including myself) would call a "horrendous hack":

```
setClass("aliased.data.frame", contains="data.frame")

make_alias <- function(original_name, alias) {
  # make sure lazy evaluation doesn't bite us
  force(original_name)
  force(alias)

  setMethod("$", signature(x="aliased.data.frame"), function(x, name) {
    if (name == alias) name <- original_name
    x[[name]]
  })
}
```

In that example I am essentially shadowing the `$` method to apply "anti-aliasing".
You would have to similarly define any generics that should support your alias.
As an example, now this would work:

```
> make_alias("a", "b")
> adf <- new("aliased.data.frame", data.frame(a=1:2))
> adf$b
[1] 1 2
> adf$a == adf$b
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

There would be tricky aspects to consider.
For example, the default `$` method for data frames does partial matching:

```
> data.frame(aa=1:2)$a
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

*Edit*

`$.data.frame` was removed from R between R 3.5 and R 3.6, so here's a new solution:

```
df <- head(iris)
comment(df) <- c(SL="Sepal.Length",SW="Sepal.Width")

`$.data.frame` <- function(e1,e2) {
  if(e2 %in% names(comment(e1)))
     e2 <- comment(e1)[e2]
  eval.parent(substitute(as.list(e1)$e2))
}

df$SL
# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4

identical(df$SL,df$Sepal.Length)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

previous solution

Here's a really quick trick using the `comment` and `comment<-` functions/attribute and the `trace` function :

```
df <- head(iris)
comment(df) <- c(SL="Sepal.Length",SW="Sepal.Width")
trace(`$.data.frame`,quote(if(name %in% names(comment(df)))
  name <- comment(df)[name]),print=FALSE)

df$SL
# [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4

identical(df$SL,df$Sepal.Length)
# [1] TRUE
```

the comment attribute is not printed by default like others would, to see it, call :

```
comment(df)
```

Cancel the `trace` call with :

```
 untrace(`$.data.frame`)
```

Comment: This is cleaner and shorter than my solution. how one can make assignment with `<-` work with this?

Comment: I'm using the existing function `comment<-` to create a comment attribute. I could have defined any other attribute but here I take advantage of the fact that this specific argument is not printed by default.

Comment: I'm getting an object not found error with this example:  
    Error in methods::.TraceWithMethods(`$.data.frame`, quote(if (name %in%  : 
  object '$.data.frame' not found

Comment: Indeed Steve I could reproduce it. I believe it was removed from R, see my new solution above.

Answer (score 2):

The example given from @Technophobe01 is good, but not very practical.
You have always to write for every alias a new function and a new class definition. A lot of work!

Coming from Lisp, I was thinking about your problem.
In Lisp, in such cases, one would define macros for looking up aliases.
The coolest thing are `reader-macros`. With reader-macros, you can change the way, how the Lisp interpreter "sees" the code.
Mostly, reader macros begin with `#`.

However, we are not in Lisp. We are in R. We don't have these possibilities.

The only way in R to let R "read" an expression with different rules is -
either to redefine the `$` method (maybe one day I will come up with this solution - or someone else ... - but one big hurdle is, that `$` is a primitive - we are not lucky ... ) , or then: you use a function (in my case: `with.alias()` shortened to: `a()` for `alias`) within which the rules are changed. This is the way, I went.

With my solution, you can do sth like this:

**How it will work**

```
# your normal data frame definition
df <- data.frame(LBTPT = 1:3)

# now df contains:
df
##   LBTPT
## 1     1
## 2     2
## 3     3


# define your aliases for each data frame in this form:
define.alias(df, list("LBTPT" = "TPT"))
# within the `define.alias()` function, you give as the first argument
# the data frame symbol, for which aliases should be defined.
# the second argument is a list of "original name" = "alias" definitions.

# This is how you call your data frame with the alias name:
a(df$TPT) # returns what d$LBTPT returns  
         ## actually `with.alias` but shortened to: `a`
# call within `a()` or `with.alias()` the data frame with the aliased column name.
# the function then looks up in the attributes `aliases` of the data frame 
# the original name of the alias for the column and
# returns the value of the originally named column.
```

**Define just three functions**

This is how you define the functions `define.alias()` and `with.alias()` and the short form `a()`:

```
define.alias <- function(df, alias.list) {
  # revert definition list
  l <- names(alias.list)
  names(l) <- alias.list
  l <- as.list(l)

  # metaprogrammatically assign "aliases" attribute to data frame
  df <- substitute(df)
  alias.list <- substitute(l)
  eval(bquote(attr(.(df), "aliases") <- .(alias.list)), env = parent.env(environment()))
}

.with.alias <- function(df.expr) {
  exp <- df.expr
  df <- exp[[2]]
  l <- eval(bquote(attr(.(exp[[2]]), "aliases")), env = parent.env(environment()))
  eval(bquote(substitute(.(exp), l)))
} 

with.alias <- function(df.expr) {
  exp <- substitute(df.expr)
  l <- eval(bquote(attr(.(exp[[2]]), "aliases")), env = parent.env(environment()))
  if (exp[[1]] == "<-") {
    l <- eval(bquote(attr(.(exp[[2]][[2]]), "aliases")), env = parent.env(environment()))
    eval(eval(bquote(substitute(.(.with.alias(exp[[2]])) <- .(exp[[3]])))), env = parent.env(environment()))
  } else {
    df <- exp[[2]]
    eval(eval(bquote(substitute(.(exp), l))), env = parent.env(environment()))
  }
} # that's it! works!
```

Tipp: you can save some typing by defining:

```
# make `with.aliases` shorter:
a <- with.aliases

## and now:
a(df$TPT) # works, too!
```

Well, but I have to work still on the `'<-'` methods.
Simple assignment within `a` works, though

```
a(df$TPT <- new.vetor)  # assigns correctly
a(df$TPT[3] <- 3)       # but this not yet ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use brackets instead of the dollar signs to reference a column this would work:

```
d <- data.frame(LBTPT=1:3)
LBTPT = "LBTPT"
TPT = "LBTPT"

d[TPT] == d[LBTPT]
```

I am afraid, however, it does address all your necessities.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of the strategies from @Technophobe01 and @Alexis to generate the following solution:

```
library(methods)

setClass("dataframe_alias", representation=representation(data="data.frame", aliases="list"))

as.dataframe_alias <- function(x, aliases=list()) {
  new("dataframe_alias", data=as.data.frame(x), aliases=aliases)
}

as.data.frame.dataframe_alias <- function(x, ...) {
  x@data
}

`$.dataframe_alias` <- function(x, name) {
  x[[name]]
}

`[[.dataframe_alias` <- function(x, name, ...) {
  if (name %in% names(x@data)) {
    x@data[[name, ...]]
  } else if (name %in% names(x@aliases)) {
    x@data[[x@aliases[[name]], ...]]
  } else {
    stop(name, " is not a name or alias for the dataframe_alias.")
  }
}

names.dataframe_alias <- function(x) {
  ret <- names(x@data)
  attr(ret, "aliases") <- x@aliases
  ret
}

alias_or_name_to_name <- function(object, alias) {
  ret <- rep(NA_character_, length(alias))
  mask_original_name <- alias %in% names(object@data)
  mask_aliased_name <-
    !mask_original_name &
    alias %in% names(object@aliases)
  mask_no_name <- !(mask_original_name | mask_aliased_name)
  if (any(mask_no_name)) {
    stop("Some aliases are not recognized as an original or aliased name: ",
         paste(alias[mask_no_name], collapse=", "))
  }
  ret[mask_original_name] <- alias[mask_original_name]
  ret[mask_aliased_name] <- unlist(object@aliases[alias])
  ret
}

#' Add an alias to a dataframe_alias
#' 
#' @param object A dataframe_alias object
#' @param ... named aliases to add in the form \code{alias=original_name}
#' @param rm Remove the alias(es)?
#' @return The updated \code{object}
#' @export
alias.dataframe_alias <- function(object, ..., rm=FALSE) {
  args <- list(...)
  if (is.null(names(args))) {
    stop("Arguments must be named")
  } else if (any(names(args) %in% "")) {
    stop("All arguments must be named")
  } else if (!all(unlist(args) %in% names(object))) {
    # all arguments must map to actual data names (indirect alises are not
    # currently permitted)
    browser()
    stop("All arguments must map to original data names")
  }
  for (nm in names(args)) {
    object@aliases[[nm]] <- args[[nm]]
  }
  object
}

foo <- as.dataframe_alias(iris, aliases=list(foo="Sepal.Length"))
foo2 <- alias(foo, bar="Sepal.Length")
```

Comment: It wasn't intuitive to me how to make some of the normal extraction functions work well with R6.  Specifically, when I tried to write `[[.dataframe_alias`, I kept getting errors.  It was probably my lack of understanding of the R6 paradigm.

Comment: @BillDenney Have you got an example set of operations and dataset that you are trying to use? Seeing those would be helpful. My sense is that you could create a generic R6 class here to do what you suggest.

Comment: The code that I gave above doesn't do everything that I want to do.  The general list of operations I'm looking for is: extract (`[`, `[[`, `$`), set (same as extract), `merge` (first try to match basic names then try to match aliases), `rbind` (and `bind_rows`), `cbind` (and `bind_cols`), and ideally the full `dplyr` verb set.  (I know I'm asking for the moon here.)

Comment: Bill, no worries. Use the iris dataset (or one of your choosing) as an example and show the operations you want using the data set. For example, I want to [Extract, index, etc] and show a test result. Just do it with a single dataset, not the alias (I think understand what you want there).

Answer (score 0):

If you use data.table then there is aliasing built in. You can

- Use data.table
- Create a list of the original column names
- Change the columns you need changed, this will be just a pointer, not a copy.
- Plug that table into your functions.
- Change the names back.

```
a <- data.table::as.data.table(survival::bladder)
originalNames <- data.table::copy(names(a))   # Create a copy of the original names
originalNames
b <- a  # Allias the data.table.  Not really needed.
data.table::setnames(b, old = 'event', new = "LBTPT")
dplyr::glimpse(b)  #  names in both data tables are changed
dplyr::glimpse(a)  #  names in both data tables are changed
data.table::setnames(a, old = names(b), new = originalNames)  # Change back to old names when you are done
dplyr::glimpse(a)  # Back to original
```

Comment: That's not actually creating an alias; I can't use both names at the same time.  It saves making a memory copy of the data, but it doesn't allow me to refer to the same column by two different names.

Comment: My method accomplishes two things the accepted method doesn't.  People who read your code will see the `setnames` and understand the change in column names.  Second, learning R6 methods will not be necessary.  In addition, my method still allows you to use code that references the columns by two different names without having two copies of the data.  The answer you accepted will just make your code very difficult for another programmer to understand.