# Can I somehow refer to a column by more than one name?

Tags: r

I am working with two data.frames which use different terminology. To keep the terminology of each data.frame intact, I am currently deliberating whether it would be an idea to simply add the columns to the other data.frame.

```
df_a <- data.frame(
        A = c("a", "b", "c"),
        B = c("a", "b", "c")
        )

df_b <- data.frame(
        same_as_A = c("a", "b", "c"),
        same_as_B = c("a", "b", "c")
        )

df_a <- cbind(df_a, df_b)
df_b <- cbind(df_b, df_a)
```

This will however become problematic as soon as I will start making changes to any of these columns. I was wondering if there is instead a way or even a trick, to refer to a column by more than one name. Obviously this does not work, but something like:

```
df_a <- data.frame(
        A & same_as_A = c("a", "b", "c"),
        B & same_as_B = c("a", "b", "c")
        )
```

Where `df_a$same_as_A` is equal to `df_a$A`

```
"a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: and why would you want to call the column with more than one name? if you are going against the basic structure of a language to solve a problem, then you have to change the perspective that you are using to tackle the problem. The name is similar to an index. It needs to be uniquely defined. I havent seen you defining a vector and desiring to put all the 3 elements (a, b, c) in the same position ie 1

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this, and it seems like a Bad Idea. Standardizing column names is a typical early step when cleaning data.

Comment: It'd be helpful to have more info about what type of data manipulation you're looking to do. From the info in this post, it seems like a good case for creating a separate lookup table or index of equivalent column names, and then subsetting based on the values in the lookup table.

Comment: Have a look at [Is It Possible to Alias data.frame names in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50426610/10488504).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive your own superclass of `data.frame`, wrap `[` and `$`, and handle aliases explicitly.

```r
aliases <- function(x, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  stopifnot(!is.null(names(dots)), all(nzchar(names(dots))))
  nms <- attr(x, "aliases")
  attr(x, "aliases") <- c(nms[!names(nms) %in% names(dots)], dots)
  if (class(x)[1] != "aliased_dataframe") {
    class(x) <- c("aliased_dataframe", class(x))
  }
  x
}

`[.aliased_dataframe` <- function(x, i, j, ...) {
  if (!inherits(x, "aliased_dataframe")) NextMethod()
  if (!missing(j) && length(j)) {
    aliases <- attr(x, "aliases")
    ind <- j %in% names(aliases)
    j[ind] <- unlist(aliases[ match(j[ind], names(aliases)) ])
  }
  NextMethod(object = x)
}
`$.aliased_dataframe` <- function(x, j, ...) {
  if (!inherits(x, "aliased_dataframe")) NextMethod()
  if (!missing(j) && length(j)) {
    aliases <- attr(x, "aliases")
    ind <- j %in% names(aliases)
    j[ind] <- unlist(aliases[ match(j[ind], names(aliases)) ])
  }
  NextMethod(object = x)
}
`$<-.aliased_dataframe` <- function(x, j, ...) {
  if (!inherits(x, "aliased_dataframe")) NextMethod()
  if (!missing(j) && length(j)) {
    aliases <- attr(x, "aliases")
    ind <- j %in% names(aliases)
    j[ind] <- unlist(aliases[ match(j[ind], names(aliases)) ])
  }
  NextMethod(object = x)
}
```

Demo:

```r
df_b <- data.frame(
        same_as_A = c("a", "b", "c"),
        same_as_B = c("a", "b", "c")
        )

df_b[, "a"]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(df_b, , "a") : undefined columns selected
df_b$a
# NULL
df_b <- aliases(df_b, a="same_as_A", b="same_as_B")
df_b[, "a"]
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
df_b$a
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
df_b$a <- c("A","B","C")
df_b
#   same_as_A same_as_B
# 1         A         a
# 2         B         b
# 3         C         c
```

Coincidentally, this works with `tbl_df` as well, but sadly not with `data.table` variants.

```r
library(tibble) # or dplyr
df_b <- tibble(df_b)
df_b[, "a"]
# Error in `stop_subscript()`:
# ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
# x Column `a` doesn't exist.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
df_b$a
# Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `a`.
# NULL
df_b <- aliases(df_b, a="same_as_A", b="same_as_B")
df_b[, "a"]
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
#   same_as_A
#   <chr>    
# 1 a        
# 2 b        
# 3 c        
df_b$a
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
df_b$a <- c("A","B","C")
df_b
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   same_as_A same_as_B
#   <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 A         a        
# 2 B         b        
# 3 C         c
```

I should note that this accommodates explicit use of `j=`, as in `df_b[,"a"]`; the shortcut of `df_b["a"]` is technically overloading the `i=` argument, and while the base `[.data.frame` is correctly inferring your intent, these S3 wrappers are not. It is not difficult to add that (just another conditional, perhaps starting with `if (missing(j) && !missing(i) && is.character(i))`), but for simplicity I"m keeping it out. Because of this, `df_b["a"]` fails.

Another note, I did not overload `[[`, so `df_b[["a"]]` returns `NULL`. If it's really important to you, one could adapt this methodology to do that as well.

Comment: This is super interesting! Thank you very much! Shame it does not work with data.table, but still very nice.

Comment: Yeah, I wrestled with `data.table` for a bit, but there is a _lot_ of optimization done internally that I thought messing with it (especially when the original question did not suggest it) was not worth my time. If you really want that, you might be able to use the new `env=` argument in the new (not-yet-released) 1.14.3, that might come a little closer (though is not really intended for aliasing of columns).